# In react-native, run minified code with debugging

Tags: react-native

I have an odd issue where I get the desired behavior when running a dev build but not a release one.  I want to debug the code, but as far as I know I can't do that when running `--configuration Release`.  I want to check if the issue has to do with minifying the js or something else.  Is there a way to run

```
react-native run-ios --minify
```

or something?  (The above command doesn't work.  `error: unknown option '--minify'`)

I've seen that you can run `react-native bundle --minify`, but I don't know how to then get the bundle onto the iOS Simulator, nor if `bundle` is the correct way to do things in React Native v0.42, as all the bundle solutions I've seen online have been v0.15ish.

Comment: your OS: Sierra 10.12.1 and Xcode: 8.1?

Comment: No, my laptop is too old.  I'm on El Capitan 10.11.6 and XCode 8.2.1

Comment: i think the problem is with Xcode version or watchman

Comment: please run these commands(launchctl unload ~/Library/LaunchAgents/com.github.facebook.watchman.plist
watchman version) and then try.

Comment: What problem are you talking about?  The difference between Development and Release?  How is unloading Watchman going to let me minify the js code?